Why is floating TOC in Nextra not working
I'm trying to add TOC to the right sidebar, like the image below.

I updated the theme.config.js, but I'm not sure how to add the toc.float. Currently, the TOC is shown in the left sidebar under the page title.
This is my theme.config.js
import { useTheme } from 'next-themes'

export default {
  logo: () => {
    const { theme } = useTheme()

    return (
      <img 
        src={theme === 'dark' ? '/images/logo/logo-white.svg' : '/images/logo/logo-grey.svg'} 
        alt="Logo" 
        style={{ height: '40px' }} /* Adjust as needed */
      />
    )
  },
  toc:true,
    // other configuration options
}

Could you please help me?
Thank you in advance.

I also raised the question in GitHub and got the following fix. For anyone else facing the same issue, please check whether there are any special characters in your frontmatter, like apostrophes ('). If so, wrap the text with double quotes "
